# Exportar dados de um objeto para arquivo csv com PHP

Tags: php, mysql, csv

Estou tentando exportar dados do banco para um arquivos CSV, porém todas as funções que encontro para realizar tal função apresentam certo tipo de erro.

Estou realizando toda a busca no banco com PDO e retornando os dados ao meu Control, porém é nesta parte que estaciono, não consigo exportar os dados.

Será que alguém pode me ajuda?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para criação de um arquivo no formato `.csv` com `PHP`, sobre dados vindo de um `array` associativo, segue exemplo abaixo:

```
<?php   

    //PDO
    $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=dbactive', 'root', 'senha');

    //COLUNAS
    $columns = $pdo->prepare("SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM information_schema.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA='dbactive' AND TABLE_NAME='tbproduct'");
    $columns->execute();
    $results_columns = $columns->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN,0);

    //DADOS
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM tbproduct');   
    $stmt->execute();
    $results = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    //CRIAÇÃO DO ARQUIVO CSV
    $from = fopen("file.csv", 'wb');

    //ADICIONANDO O CABEÇALHO
    fwrite($from, '"'.implode('";"', $results_columns).'"'.PHP_EOL);

    //ADICIONANDO OS DADOS
    foreach ($results as $idx => $result) 
    {       
        //fputcsv( $from, $result );
        $results[$idx] = str_replace("\"", "\"\"", $result);        
        fwrite($from, '"'.implode('";"', $results[$idx]).'"'.PHP_EOL);
    }   
    fclose($from);
```

No [packagist](https://packagist.org/) tem vários pacotes que podem ser integrados facilmente ao seu projeto, segue abaixo 3 excelente:

- [mnshankar/csv](https://packagist.org/packages/mnshankar/csv)
- [goodby/csv](https://packagist.org/packages/goodby/csv)
- [keboola/csv](https://packagist.org/packages/keboola/csv)

***EDIÇÃO:***

A primeira rotina gera o arquivo em disco e a essa pega esse arquivo gerado no disco e manda para download.

```
header("Content-type: application/csv");   
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=file.csv");   
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
$path = "file.csv";
$from = fopen($path, 'r');
$csv = fread($from, filesize($path));   
fclose($from);
echo $csv;
```

Comment: Melhorou bastante, só precisava ver como resolver se tiver algum ' na string. Talvez precise de uma substituição de `'` por `\'` - exemplo: se o DB tiver um campo com `caixa d'agua, cheia`  vai ficar `'caixa d'agua, cheia'` e zoar o CSV. Vou sair, mas amanhã dou uma olhada se ficou legal, tá quase lá. Depois de ler, pode marcar com flag de obsoleto aqui, pra nao ficar bagunça na sua resposta.

Comment: Bom dia, primeiramente obrigado pela ajuda, estou conseguindo salvar os dados no arquivo CSV, porém ao solicitar no sistema que efetue a exportação ele simplesmente salva no arquivo exterior onde eu defini, o que eu queria é que ao clicar no botão ele efetuasse o download do arquivo exibindo o mesmo ao usuário. Outro ponto que consegui com recursos do Mysqli é que o mesmo retornava o nome das colunas exportadas sendo que desta forma no PDO somente retorna os dados da tabela. Será que poderia me ajudar mais uma vez?

Comment: @LucasCarvalho eu coloque um outra parte da EDIÇÃO. Espero que ajude

Comment: Ok, valeu cara, funcionou, apesar dos valores estarem repetidos em algumas linhas, porém isso possivelmente seja fácil de arrumar. Caso não seja muito abuso de seu intelecto, você sabe alguma maneira onde eu consiga retornar o nome da coluna na primeira linha do arquivos CSV? ouvi dizer que não seria possível tal tarefa, porém com Mysqli há uma maneira de se realizar, logo creio que com PDO também seja possível. Muito grato pela sua ajuda.

Comment: `"SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM information_schema.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA='dbactive' AND TABLE_NAME='tbproduct'"` eu fiz a edição e você adeque ao seu sistema aonde TABLE_SCHEMA é o nome do seu banco e TABLE_NAME é o nome de sua tabela.

Comment: -1 Só pra ficar registrado: Tem várias coisas ruins nessa resposta: Pra que usar implode pra gerar as linhas do CSV, sendo que o php já tem a função `fputcsv`? Outra é que lê todo o `csv` pra memória pra responder no servidor, sendo que pode usar o `readfile`

Answer (score 6):

O PHP já tem uma função pronta pra isso:

> http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php

Um exemplo, aproveitando o código do colega João:

```
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=dbactive', 'root', 'senha');
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM tbproduct');   
$stmt->execute();
$results = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$fccd = fopen( 'file.csv', 'w' );
foreach ( $results as $fields ) {
    fputcsv( $fccd, $fields );
}
fclose( $fccd );
```

Se preferir escolher os caracteres delimitadores:

```
    fputcsv( $fccd, $fields, ';', '"', '\' );
```

Assim teremos a separação por `;`, campos com aspas duplas `"` e escapados por `\`;

Comment: Bom dia, primeiramente obrigado pela ajuda, estou conseguindo salvar os dados no arquivo CSV, porém ao solicitar no sistema que efetue a exportação ele simplesmente salva no arquivo exterior onde eu defini, o que eu queria é que ao clicar no botão ele efetuasse o download do arquivo exibindo o mesmo ao usuário. Outro ponto que consegui com recursos do Mysqli é que o mesmo retornava o nome das colunas exportadas sendo que desta forma no PDO somente retorna os dados da tabela. Será que poderia me ajudar mais uma vez?

Comment: O certo seria pedir pra quem vc marcou que resolveu o problema né :P  A parte do PDO foi exemplo, a gravacao do CSV funciona igualzinho no mysqli. Aliás, mysqli é superior ao PDO, mas como você pos só uma parte do problema na pergunta, eu resolvi o que vc perguntou só. Sobre fazer download, já tá explicado na pergunta original linkada. Quanto à sua duvida, se quer por os títulos, basta pegar os campos do mysqli e acrescentar mais um `fputcsv( $fccd, $titulos, ';', '"', '\' );` ANTES do loop. $titulos no caso é um array com titulos. Fica a sugestão de quando for assim, já colocar na pergunta.